# Read gz file and get the last 24 hrs line python

Tags: python, gzip

I have three file: 2 `.gz` files and 1 `.log` file. These files are pretty big. Below I have a sample copy of my original data. I want to extract the entries that correspond to the last 24 hours.

```
a.log.1.gz

2018/03/25-00:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/25-10:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom
2018/03/25-20:08:50.486601 1.5M     7FE9D3D41706     qojfcmqcacaeia
2018/03/25-24:08:50.980519  16K     7FE9BD1AF707     user: number is 93823004
2018/03/26-00:08:50.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700
2018/03/26-10:08:51.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0
2018/03/26-15:08:51.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:

a.log.2.gz
2018/03/26-20:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/26-24:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom
2018/03/27-00:08:50.486601 1.5M     7FE9D3D41706     qojfcmqcacaeia
2018/03/27-10:08:50.980519  16K     7FE9BD1AF707     user: number is 93823004
2018/03/27-20:08:50.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700
2018/03/27-24:08:51.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0
2018/03/28-00:08:51.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:

a.log
2018/03/28-10:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/28-20:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom

** Desired Result**
result.txt
2018/03/27-20:08:50.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700
2018/03/27-24:08:51.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0
2018/03/28-00:08:51.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:
2018/03/28-10:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/28-20:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom
```

I am not sure how to get the entries that cover the last 24 hours.

And I want to run the below function on last 24 hours of data.

```
def _clean_logs(line):
    # noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    clean_line = clean_line.strip()
    clean_line = clean_line.lstrip('0123456789.- ')
    cleaned_log = " ".join(
        [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, get_wordnet_pos(word)) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(clean_line) if
         word not in Stopwords.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS and 2 < len(word) <= 30 and not word.startswith('_')])
    cleaned_log = cleaned_log.replace('"', ' ')

    return cleaned_log
```

Comment: So, what have attempted so far?

Comment: @ChrisHunt, I was trying to read and append all files. But I ended up with one big file. This solution is not working out. Because in my real scenario I have 40 big file. If I append all 40 files, then processing is becoming very slow.

Comment: @ChrisHunt, I want to clean each line using the function I have added in the question, present in last 24 hours text file.

Comment: You should make a new question with the specific information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import glob
import gzip
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


def open_file(path):
    if Path(path).suffix == '.gz':
        return gzip.open(path, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
    else:
        return open(path, encoding='utf-8')


def parsed_entries(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)


def earlier():
    return (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S')


def get_files():
    return ['a.log'] + list(reversed(sorted(glob.glob('a.log.*'))))


output = open('output.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8')


files = get_files()


cutoff = earlier()


for i, path in enumerate(files):
    with open_file(path) as f:
        lines = parsed_entries(f)
        # Assumes that your files are not empty
        date, line = next(lines)
        if cutoff <= date:
            # Skip files that can just be appended to the output later
            continue
        for date, line in lines:
            if cutoff <= date:
                # We've reached the first entry of our file that should be
                # included
                output.write(line)
                break
        # Copies from the current position to the end of the file
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, output)
        break
else:
    # In case ALL the files are within the last 24 hours
    i = len(files)

for path in reversed(files[:i]):
    with open_file(path) as f:
        # Assumes that your files have trailing newlines.
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, output)

# Cleanup, it would get closed anyway when garbage collected or process exits.
output.close()
```

Then if we make some test log files:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "2019/01/15-00:00:00.000000 hi" > a.log.1
echo "2019/01/31-00:00:00.000000 hi2" > a.log.2
echo "2019/01/31-19:00:00.000000 hi3" > a.log
gzip a.log.1 a.log.2
```

and run our script, it outputs the expected result (for this point in time)

```
2019/01/31-00:00:00.000000 hi2
2019/01/31-19:00:00.000000 hi3
```

Comment: `def parser_log(file):
    counter = 0
    for line in reversed(list(file)):
        line = line.split('.', maxsplit=1)
        yield (line[0],line[1])
        counter = counter + 1`

Comment: I have written parser_log() to parse the entries. Could you please look into it because when I run this function I get only one value for date_part and line.

Comment: @user15051990 that's pretty close - but you need to make sure **not** to do `list(file)` since that will consume all the lines. Our solution depends on only consuming 1 line at a time since we use `shutil.copyfileobj` to copy the rest of the file. I have added an implementation of `parsed_entries` to my answer so you can compare.

Comment: Thanks Chris. One more quick question, In output file I am getting only the last file text. It is not copying from the current position to the end of the file. Any comments? And else part is not needed in my case.

Comment: To debug I would do something like this: add logging statements in the first `for` loop to print each filename, one inside the `if cutoff <= date`, and one inside the second `for` loop (not the nested one). This should verify at least that all the files you expect to see are getting processed. If you have `a.1.log.gz`, `a.2.log.gz`, `a.3.log.gz`, `a.log` and the 24 hour mark is in `a.2.log.gz` you would expect to see: `a.log` (skipped), `a.3.log.gz` (skipped), `a.2.log.gz`, then `a.3.log.gz`, `a.log` from the second loop.

Comment: I debugged it. Edited your answer. Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: That doesn't seem quite right. If we want the entries to show up in order then we must start with the first one chronologically - the suggested edit would result in the more recent files appearing first. Is `files` a list for you? If it is an iterator then that could cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, files is a list for me. Could you please suggest what changes I need to make? And yes, files are not stored in chronological order.

Comment: I added the rest of the required functions and a script to test - it seems to work as expected for me but that should be enough for you to test and debug yourself.

Comment: One quick question, have written function `process_line(line)` which cleans the log file. Can you please tell me which is the best way to call this function? Because in `code where we are skipping file to copy at end, copies all the lines at once so I am not sure where to call process_line`. And another question is `I want to split file if file size becomes more than 256MB`.

Answer (score 0):

Working with log files often involves pretty large amounts of data, thus reading in ascending order and reading everything everytime is not desired since it wastes a lot of resources.

The fastest way to accomplish your goal that immediately came to my mind (better approaches will certainly exist) is a very simple random search: we search through the logfile(s) in reversed order, thus beginning with the newest first. Instead of visiting all lines, you just arbitrarily choose some `stepsize` and only look at *some* lines each `stepsize`. This way, you can search through Gigabytes of data in a very short time.

Additionally, this approach does *not* require to store each line of a file in memory, but only some lines and the final result.

When `a.log` is the current log file, we begin searching here:

```
with open("a.log", "rb+") as fh:
```

Since we are only interested in the last 24 hours, we jump to the end first and save the timestamp to search for as a formatted string:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)  # last 24h
# jump to logfile's end
fh.seek(0, 2)  # <-- '2': search relative to file's end
index = fh.tell()  # current position in file; here: logfile's *last* byte
```

Now we can begin our random search. Your line appear to be about 65 characters long on average, hence we move a multiple of that.

```
average_line_length = 65
stepsize = 1000

while True:
    # we move a step back
    fh.seek(index - average_line_length * stepsize, 2)

    # save our current position in file
    index = fh.tell()

    # we try to read a "line" (multiply avg. line length times a number
    # large enough to cover even large lines. Ignore largest lines here,
    # since this is an edge cases ruining our runtime. We rather skip
    # one iteration of the loop then)
    r = fh.read(average_line_length * 10)

    # our results now contains (on average) multiple lines, so we
    # split first
    lines = r.split(b"\n")

    # now we check for our timestring
    for l in lines:
        # your timestamps are formatted like '2018/03/28-20:08:48.985053'
        # I ignore minutes, seconds, ... here, just for the sake of simplicity
        timestr = l.split(b":")  # this gives us b'2018/03/28-20' in timestr[0]

        # next we convert this to a datetime
        found_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr[0], "%Y/%m/%d-%H")

        # finally, we compare if the found time is not inside our 24hour margin
        if found_time < timestamp:
            break
```

With this code we will only end up searching a few lines each `stepsize` (here: 1000 lines) as long as we are inside our last 24 hours. Once we left the 24 hours, we *know* that at most we went exactly `stepsize` * `average_line_length` too far up in the file.

Filtering this "went too far" becomes very easy then:

```
# read in file's contents from current position to end
contents = fh.read()

# split for lines
lines_of_contents = contents.split(b"\n")

# helper function for removing all lines older than 24 hours
def check_line(line):
    # split to extract datestr
    tstr = line.split(b":")
    # convert this to a datetime
    ftime = datetime.datetime.strptime(tstr[0], "%Y/%m/%d-%H")

    return ftime > timestamp

# remove all lines that are older than 24 hours
final_result = filter(check_line, lines_of_contents)
```

Since `contents` covers all of the remaining contents of our file (and `lines` all lines, which is simply `contents` split at linebreaks `\n`) we can easily use `filter` to get our desired result.

Each line in `lines` will be fed to `check_line`, which returns `True` if the line's time is `> timestamp` and `timestamp` is our datetime object describing exactly `now - 1day`. This means that `check_line` will return `False` for all lines older than `timestamp` and `filter` will remove those lines.

Obviously, this is far from optimal, but it is easy to understand and easily extendable to filtering for minutes, seconds, ...

Additionally, covering multiple files is also easy: you just need `glob.glob` to find all possible files, start with the newest file and add another loop: you would search through the files until our while loop fails for the first time, then break and read all remaining contents from the current file + all contents from all files visited before.

Roughly, something like this:

```
final_lines = lst()

for file in logfiles:
    # our while-loop
    while True:
       ...
    # if while-loop did not break all of the current logfile's content is
    # <24 hours of age
    with open(file, "rb+") as fh:
        final_lines.extend(fh.readlines())
```

This way you simply store all lines of a logfile, if all lines are <24 hours of age. If the loop breaks at some point, i.e. we have found a logfile and the exact line >24 hours of age, extend `final_lines` by `final_result` since this will cover only the lines <24 hours of age.

Comment: Hey this is awesome. Thank you so much for this solution. But I have written some code which combines all the log now I want to do processing on that to get last 24 hrs content. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: getting error `TypeError: strptime() argument1 must be str, not bytes` when I am implementing this line `found_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr[0], "%Y/%m/%d-%H")`